# Does baneling building attack do splash damage to units?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

If you right click on a building, banelings will attack it do much more damage than usual. Does the splash from this attack damage any units who are stood nearby? And, if so, how much?

If I set the building attack to autocast, will the banelings attack buildings in preference to units, or still attack units as first prio, then buildings if they can't reach any units?

Thanks :)

Comment: why don't you just try it out at unit test map? It'll take for about 3 min ^_^

Comment: @Meta That would not have given other interested users of this site the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Banelings usually prefer to attack units and don't attack buildings unless manually ordered to do so. When "Attack Structure" is set to auto cast, banelings will prefer to attack buildings and only go for units if there are no buildings in sight.

When a baneling explodes next to a building and a unit, the building will take 80 damage and the unit will take 20/35, no matter why the baneling exploded. If the building or the unit was targeted, or if the baneling exploded because it got killed or the player manually hit "Explode" makes no difference.

Answer (score 6):

Concerning your first question, yes, the splash damage does still harm other units around it.

Banelings always do 80 damage to structures, 35 damage to light armored, and 20 to everything else in a radius.